# Check whether reporting occurred within a two year frame for each entity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Not sure how to do this in an elegant way.
I need to create a variable that shows me, as whether the two yearly Audit report occurred on time: `ON_TIME: (yes - no`)`.  In the dummy dateset below, I can only refer to` ON_TIME: (yes - no`)`if I was to compare the same IDs of consecutive Dates, because I have data from 2016 till today. How do I make sure I compare the right pairs?
Would you rank them first? How?

in the example below ON_TIME should show:

```
ID       ON_TIME 
11356   yes
489734  yes
9458    no

SELECT '11356' AS ID, '2016-06-15' AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2016-06-15')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '9458' AS ID, '2018-05-12' AS Audit_Date , (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2018-05-12')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '489734' AS ID, '2017-12-01'  AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2017-12-01')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '11356' AS ID, '2018-06-15' AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2016-06-15')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '9458' AS ID, '2020-08-12' AS Audit_Date , (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2018-05-12')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '489734' AS ID, '2019-11-31'  AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2017-12-01')) AS Next_Audit_Due
```

I want to create a new variable called "on_time" that shows whether an audit has occurred for en entity(ID) within a two year time frame from the time they had their last Audit (Audit_date). If possible I DO NOT want to transpose the dataset. The entities (ID) need to stay under each other.

Comment: Its not clear to me what your definition of `on_time` is? What values are you comparing to determine that?

Comment: I want to create a new variable called "on_time" that shows whether an audit has occurred for en entity(ID)  within a two year time frame from the time they had their last Audit (Audit_date). If possible I DO NOT want to transpose the dataset. The entities (ID) need to stay under each other.

Comment: @Anna the sample data contains the date '2019-11-31' and there is no such date!  I switched it to '2019-12-01' in my answer

Comment: I wonder what your tried? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unsure whether you wanted to return all rows, or just the latest rows. Anyway this solution, using `LAG`, allows either.

Its also not clear how `Next_Audit_Due` relates to the question.

```
WITH TestData AS (
    SELECT '11356' AS ID, '2016-06-15' AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2016-06-15')) AS Next_Audit_Due
    UNION
    SELECT '9458' AS ID, '2018-05-12' AS Audit_Date , (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2018-05-12')) AS Next_Audit_Due
    UNION
    SELECT '489734' AS ID, '2017-12-01'  AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2017-12-01')) AS Next_Audit_Due
    UNION
    SELECT '11356' AS ID, '2018-06-15' AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2016-06-15')) AS Next_Audit_Due
    UNION
    SELECT '9458' AS ID, '2020-08-12' AS Audit_Date , (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2018-05-12')) AS Next_Audit_Due
    UNION
    SELECT '489734' AS ID, '2019-11-30'  AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2017-12-01')) AS Next_Audit_Due
)
SELECT ID, Audit_Date, Next_Audit_Due
  , CASE WHEN Lagged_Audit_Date IS NULL THEN 'N/A' WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 2, Lagged_Audit_Date) >= Audit_Date THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END [ON_TIME]
FROM (
  SELECT id, CONVERT(DATE, Audit_Date, 23) Audit_Date, Next_Audit_Due
    , LAG(Audit_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Audit_Date ASC) Lagged_Audit_Date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Audit_Date DESC) RowNumber
  FROM TestData
) X
-- Comment out to only show the latest row per ID
-- WHERE RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY id, Audit_Date ASC;
```

Returns:

```
ID      Audit_Date  Next_Audit_Due          ON_TIME
11356   2016-06-15  2018-06-15 00:00:00.000 N/A
11356   2018-06-15  2018-06-15 00:00:00.000 Yes
489734  2017-12-01  2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 N/A
489734  2019-11-30  2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 Yes
9458    2018-05-12  2020-05-11 00:00:00.000 N/A
9458    2020-08-12  2020-05-11 00:00:00.000 No
```

And as Steve noted, there was an invalid date in there...

Comment: Perfect, this solution is brilliant: , LAG(Audit_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Audit_Date ASC) Lagged_Audit_Date -  what I had was a sub-query, whereby a I missed to reference the lagged date. As I had the lagged date prior to the sub-query, I just could not get it working. Next time, I will post more of what I have tried.  Thanks heaps though, this is a cool solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this meets the requirements

Data

```
drop table if exists #ontime;
go
with data as (
SELECT '11356' AS ID, '2016-06-15' AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2016-06-15')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '9458' AS ID, '2018-05-12' AS Audit_Date , (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2018-05-12')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '489734' AS ID, '2017-12-01'  AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2017-12-01')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '11356' AS ID, '2018-06-15' AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2016-06-15')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '9458' AS ID, '2020-08-12' AS Audit_Date , (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2018-05-12')) AS Next_Audit_Due
UNION
SELECT '489734' AS ID, '2019-12-01'  AS Audit_Date, (DATEADD(DAY,730,'2017-12-01')) AS Next_Audit_Due )
select id, Audit_Date, Next_Audit_Due
into #ontime
from data;
```

Query

```
select id, max(case when cast(Audit_Date as date)=cast(Next_Audit_Due as date) then 1 else 0 end) on_time
from #ontime
group by id;
```

Output

```
id      on_time
11356   1
489734  1
9458    0
```